# What are the differences between "inverse", "reverse", and "converse"?

Tags: differences

What distinctions can be made among the meanings of the words "inverse", "reverse", "converse", and, for good measure, "transverse" and "obverse"? Is it ever possible to use some of them interchangeably?

Are they the same for purposes of casual discourse? Do the differences become more salient in a particular technical context, such as engineering, math, or linguistics?

Comment: I've marked the most exhaustive answer so far as the accepted answer, but I hope that doesn't discourage anyone from adding any specific, odd, technical, or otherwise interesting uses of these words.

Comment: For the logic terms, see [https://www.quora.com/Debate/What-is-the-difference-between-inverse-converse-opposite-etc](https://www.quora.com/Debate/What-is-the-difference-between-inverse-converse-opposite-etc)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**inverse**: opposite or contrary in position, direction, order, or effect
*in mathematics* - something obtained by inversion or something that can be applied to an element to produce its identity element
**reverse**: opposite primarily in direction
*in law* - reverse or annul
*in printing* - make print white in a block of solid color or half tone
*in electronics* - in the direction that does not allow significant current
*in geology* - denoting a fault or faulting in which a relative downward movement occurred in the strata situated on the underside of the fault plane
**converse**: corresponding yet opposing
*in mathematics* - a theorem whose hypothesis and conclusion are the conclusion and hypothesis of another
*also a brand of shoe*
**transverse**: situated across from something
**obverse**: the opposite or counterpart of something (particularly a truth)
*in biology* - narrower at the base or point of attachment than at the apex or top

<sub>from NOAD</sub>

*Reverse* is the only one I've commonly heard in casual speech and only referring to the direction of a car (in US... don't know about UK et al).  Some could be used interchangeably, but it would be best to avoid it considering that each generally has a specific meaning in its context.

Comment: It's worth noting that all of these are borrowed whole from Latin. "Vertere" is productive root in Latin but "verse" is not a productive root in English.

Comment: There is also _averse_ to risk.

Comment: Confusingly, notwithstanding the definition above, _obverse_ is often used as the opposite of _reverse_.

Comment: (I mean, in those few cases where it is used at all.)

Comment: @Charles: excellent observation!

Comment: The "reverse -- _in printing_" entry is interesting. I would've thought that was "inverse".

Comment: @JoshCaswell I was thinking the same. verified this usage for myself by checking [a random](http://www.printindustry.com/Glossary.aspx) printing glossary. at the same time, getting this effect is indeed called 'inverse' in at least photoshop, of all digital image-related programs.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Sure, but "versus" is, right?

Answer (score 16):

*obverse*: [the front side of a coin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obverse_and_reverse) (as opposed to the reverse)

[*converse*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_%28logic%29) and [*inverse*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_%28logic%29) in mathematical logic take a conditional hypothesis and swap or negate its clauses, respectively:

- Original hypothesis: "If I have received $100 in the mail today, I will buy a pair of pants tomorrow."
- Converse: "If I buy a pair of pants tomorrow, I have received $100 in the mail today."
- Inverse: "If I have not received $100 in the mail today, I will not buy a pair of pants  tomorrow."

The truth or falsehood of the original hypothesis is not equivalent to either the converse or the inverse, but the converse and the inverse are equivalent to each other.

Comment: Those are great! Do you think it would be useful to add an example of logical "obverse", which is linked to from the WP "inverse" page?

Comment: uh.... I answered converse and inverse because I've known about them (+ contrapositive, which is more immediately useful). I glanced at the "obversion" page in wikipedia and my eyes glazed over.

Comment: Late to the party: if your original statement is P => Q, then the converse is Q => P and the inverse is !P => !Q. It happens that the inverse and the converse are logically equivalent, but they are both ways of obtaining statements that are related but logically non-equivalent to the original statement. In contrast the obverse applies to statements of the form "For each s P(s) is true" (where P is some predicate) to obtain an *equivalent* statement. The obverse of that statement is "There is no s such that P(s) is false". Note that it doesn't apply to the general setting of propositions P, Q.

Answer (score 3):

These are good definitions and clarifications, but since I don't see direct answers, I will offer one.  As a software engineer, I am familiar with logic, and so *converse* and *inverse* are everyday words for me.

The converse, defined as swapping hypothesis and conclusion, is of course a position change.  Since reverse indicates direction, I have often heard and even used *reverse* as a natural substitute for *converse*.

Think of someone saying, "If I have to do it, you do too!"  A common reply would be "And the reverse!"  This is actually referring to the converse, but that would not be said by most people with whom I am familiar.

I believe that those are the only two that would be confused in casual discourse, and that the differences would indeed become more salient in technical contexts.

Comment: "As a software engineer, I am familiar with logic"

Not a requirement for a software engineer. Sometimes I wonder if it is discouraged. I blame JavaScript <s>

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget the **contrapositive**, which goes from 'If I get $100, I shall buy a coat.' 'If I have not bought a coat, I have not received $100.'and *is* true when the original assertion were.

If
  A --> B
(condition 'A' *always* implies condition 'B')

Converse: 
        B --> A
 False---more than one road can lead to Rome (one might not have got the $100 but instead opted for cheaper pants)

Inverse: (for the 'not' operator '~') 
       ~A --> ~B

 False, for the same reason as is the Converse.  (Remember,'A-->B' doesn't mean that A were the only way to get to B.)

Contrapositive:
     ~B-->~A

True, if the original assertion is---if fire *always* implies smoke, then 'no smoke'  implies 'no fire'...and so the existence of 'no smoke' and 'flame' with a correctly used propane torch means that the original assertion is not true for all definitions of fire.

Comment: Your converse example switches to pants instead of coats. ;)

Comment: Note that you changed tense in the sentence; I think it should be "If I shall not buy a coat, I won't get $100". Also, I think describing the con-/inverse as false is inaccurate; it would be more accurate to say that they don't follow from the original proposition. Formally, <math>(A implies B) does-not-imply (B implies A)</math> but not <math>(A implies B) implies (B does-not-imply A)</math>. Aside: a cute example of the contrapositive is "what doesn't make me stronger kills me". (Off-topic debate: is this a reductio ad absurdum of Nietzsche's aphorism?)